# How to bring to front an application opened using PsExec

Tags: psexec

I'm invoking an application on a remote machine using PsExec (called from a C# test project). The invoked application has a GUI and also listens to a TCP port. At certain times I need to send it a command (using TCP) that takes a screenshot of the application and returns the screenshot back to my test.

The issue is that for that to work properly, the window of the application should be in front of other windows, but for some reason, PsExec always opens in behind all other application windows.

Note that **I do use the /i** switch and I can see the window if I bring it to front manually (e.g. using Alt+Tab), but I can't make PsExec to open it in front of other applications.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with psexec alone. You could make a program to bring the app to the front, and run that with psexec, before taking the screenshot?

Comment: I was thinking about that, but hoped I'd found an easier solution.